# Matlab Title Formatting

Tags: matlab, formatting

For matlab script, when I create a title for a plot, I use the following command:

```
title(['Input ', x, '; Output', y]);
```

However, this returns a newline character whenever I use ',' on the above string. So it looks like the following:

```
Input
xValue
Output
yValue
```

Anyone knows how to make these strings appear on the same line? Thanks.

Comment: The `title` function does not do this by itself, nor does concatenating strings using `[string1, string2]` (which is the same as simply `[string1 string2]`), so there must newline characters in `x` or `y`. That's assuming that `x` and `y` are strings. If they are not, you must convert them to strings first using, e.g., `titleStr = sprintf('Input %d; Output %d', x, y);`.

Comment: @wakjah: I tried it; the output will be as given in the question if x and y are cell values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the output shown, I'm inferring that `x` and `y` are cell values. If so, you could use something like:

```
title(strcat('Input=>', num2str(cell2mat(x)), '; Output=>', num2str(cell2mat(y))))
```

The result would be as follows for `x={1}` and `y={2}`:

[image]

The reason you got the output as you did initially was that, since `x` and `y` were cells, MATLAB automatically converted your statement to

```
title([{'Input '}, x, {'; Output'}, y]);
```

meaning that you passed a cell array to title; as such, it displayed each part of the title in a separate line.

Now, if on the other hand, `x` and `y` were simple numbers, use:

```
title(strcat('Input=>', num2str(x), '; Output=>', num2str(y)))
```